# Powershell script works in ISE, shell, and cmd.exe but not as a task

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm having trouble getting a powershell script to execute from the task manager.

It does execute from the ISE where I developed it, but not from the task manager.  I've been working on getting this to work for a while and I've slowly got the script to get closer and closer to executing.  I've been testing the calling the script from the command shell and that has helped me figure out some of the problems.  However I can't get this last error to quit and hoping for some help.  This is the way that I call it from the task manager and cmd.exe

powershell -noexit -command "& c:\processdata_sql\processdatatesting\processdata.ps1"

I get pages and pages of errors 
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument: "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to Int32"

Again this code does work from the ISE a powershell shell and cmd.exe.

Hopefully someone can help with this.

Comment: Well the problem isn't actually with the ExecuteNonQuery it's earlier in the system.  The problem is that the task isn't finding the X drive which is a mounted drive.  This driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer to this situation although it makes no sense to me.

Here's how I found it.  I decided I would just map the network drive I was trying to get to using the New-PSDrive cmdlet.  However, to update the help for that I needed to run the shell as an administrator.  So I did that and updated the help files and then started testing the PSDive cmdlets and while I was doing that I noticed that as an administrator when I ran Get-PSDrive it was not seeing my mapped drives!!  Yes I was running the task with "Run with highest privilege" checked.  I went back in and unchecked that box and everything started working.